# Does 'repo' have a command like 'git commit' to Record changes to the local repository

Tags: android, git, repo

I'm working on a project recently, the project using 'repo' to manage the code. In the 'Tina_v3' folder, there are many subdirectory using git to manage the source code; such as folder: target, package,etc. I'm not familiar about 'repo';
my question is : how to record the whole project by using 'repo' command, Does 'repo' have a command like "git commit", I don't like to using 'repo upload';
[image]

Comment: I would start here: https://source.android.com/docs/setup/develop

Comment: Repo wraps some git commands. You could just use git commands like `git commit`, `git push`.

Comment: But in the root directory：tina_v3, there is no .git folder; So , I can't using git command. Any other idea?

Comment: @DonnieYang If the codebase is downloaded by `repo init && repo sync`, there should be a `.repo` in the root directory of the codebase. In `.repo/manifest.xml`, you can find all repositories and their local paths.

Comment: Yes, but even I do that  'git commit'  for all repositories one by one; when I back to root directory, then execute: $./repo start --all newbranch , the code is still the old version before 'git commit';     I think there is no other way except by using the  "./repo upload" command to upload the whole project to cloud, then someone get the code merged .